# How to remove easing from custom cursor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I received help from a user on here to add easing to a custom cursor I created, but i was using jQuery and the guy who helped me provided a vanilla JS solution which works great,
but now I need to remove the easing from the cursor which has been worked on since then.

```js
  let cursor = document.querySelector('#custom-cursor');

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    document.body.classList.add('custom-cursor-moved')

    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      $('#custom-cursor').remove();
    } else {
      cursor.style.display = 'block';
    }


    let {
      clientX: x,
      clientY: y
    } = evt;
    let scale = 1;

    if (evt.target.matches('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i')) {
      cursor.classList.add('active');
      scale = 0.5;
    } else {
      cursor.classList.remove('active');
    }

    cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${scale})`;

  });
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}


.custom-cursor-moved,
.custom-cursor-moved * {
  cursor: none !important;
}


#custom-cursor {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fb4d98;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  transition: transform ease-out 0.15s, border 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
}

#custom-cursor.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom-cursor"></div>
<span>HOVER OVER ME</span>
```

Comment: Could I get some clarification? do you want to remove the easing effect?

Comment: To do that, you only need to remove transition in `#custom-cursor`.

Comment: yes please, but only on the cursor position, i need the easing to work on the opacity, scaling, colour etc

Comment: Can you provide an example where the opacity/scaling/colour have easing?   Seems to be identical if you remove the `transition` but perhaps will have an effect if there's a non-custom-cursor area

Comment: @freedomn-m Ive added a span, hover over it and you will see the easing on the scaling, colour, opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the easing from the x/y change, you need to remove the `translate(x,y)`

```
cursor.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
```

you can then add the x/y directly (not via the translate)

```
cursor.style.top = `${y}px`
cursor.style.left = `${x}px`
```

Updated snippet

```js
let cursor = document.querySelector('#custom-cursor');

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    document.body.classList.add('custom-cursor-moved')

    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      $('#custom-cursor').remove();
    } else {
      cursor.style.display = 'block';
    }


    let {
      clientX: x,
      clientY: y
    } = evt;
    let scale = 1;

    if (evt.target.matches('a,span,[onclick],img,video,i')) {
      cursor.classList.add('active');
      scale = 0.5;
    } else {
      cursor.classList.remove('active');
    }

    cursor.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    cursor.style.top = `${y}px`
    cursor.style.left = `${x}px`

  });
```

```css
#custom-cursor {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fb4d98;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  transition: transform ease-out 0.15s, border 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
}

#custom-cursor.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom-cursor"></div>
<span>HOVER OVER ME</span>
```

Comment: Try to move the cursor on "HOVER OVER ME", the cursor goes back to the original size.

Comment: Ive just noticed one issue with this, the custom cursor is no longer not correctly positioned with the mouse. Ive edited the code to show the mouse cursor.

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing 'top' & 'left' in the CSS to 'margin-top' & 'margin-left'

Comment: @LearningMathematics yes, that's how it's intended to work (as it does in the question) - to demonstrate the switch between active and not active, OP added that to their original code to help.

Answer (score 0):

The line causing the easing effect is this:

```
transition: transform ease-out 0.15s, border 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
```

So just deleting it should do what you want. Perhaps you were looking for a solution in the javascript itself if you're used to jQuery.

It is not possible to write css to affect the transition of the scaling but not the position. If that's what you need, you would have to wrap it in another element.

```
 <div id="cursor-position"><div id="custom-cursor"></div></div>
```

```
#cursor-position {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```
let cursorPosition = document.querySelector("#cursor-position");
let cursor = document.querySelector("#custom-cursor");
// ...
cursor.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
cursorPosition.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - you should be able to do "copy snippet to answer" (if this doesn't appear, you can still do it manually) then make your changes to show it working.  Do keep the description as code-only answers are not as helpful.

Comment: Thep problem with this is that removing that line of CSS removes the easing effect on the scaling and colour change of the cursor on hover. I need those to remain, just the cursor position easing needs to be removed.

Comment: I've tried to add something to address that now, but the other answer is better.